# Google Sheet - Is it possible do concatenate a cell in a formula

Tags: google-sheets

I want to include a value from the `Datas` tab.

So my formula should be : `=Datas!A1071`.

But how I can use the value include in another my current tab to replace the `1071` part.

Something like this : `=Datas!A"B1"`.

Is is possible ?

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qboMqSbrXLervVQcEAfWpb_HB9m6EPbQxUbmeAZXtiE/edit#gid=1569842665

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function.

```cpp
=INDIRECT("Datas!A"&B1)
```

Or [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)

```cpp
=INDEX(Datas!A:A,B1)
```